# Re-writing church numerals function

Tags: scheme, lisp, lambda-calculus, sicp

In SICP it defines the church numerals for positive numbers as follows:

```
(define zero (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)))
(define (add-1 n)
    (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f (n f) x))))
```

The following is my 'best attempt' to rewrite this for my own understanding, here passing explicit arguments to one function:

```
(define (church f x n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) x)                       ; zero case: return x
    (else (f (church f x (- n 1)))))) ; otherwise f(f(f...(x))) n times

(church square 3 2)
81
```

And then redefining `zero` I would have:

```
(define (zero2 f)
  (lambda (x) (church f x 0)))
```

And `add-one` as:

```
(define (add-1 n f)
  (lambda (x) (church f x (+ n 1))))
```

Or, if we have to defer the `f` argument then adding a wrapper-lambda:

```
(define (add-1 n)
  (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (church f x (+ n 1)))))
```

Do I have a correct understanding of this? if so, why the oh-so-complicated-syntax at the top for the `add-1` or `zero` procedures (note: I'm guessing it's not that complicated and I'm just not fully understanding what it's doing). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda` calculus is a sub set of Scheme that does not allow more than one argument and `lambda`. With combinations of lambdas you can make any construct:

```
(define false (lambda (true) (lambda (false) false)))
(define true (lambda (true) (lambda (false) true)))
(define if (lambda (pred) (lambda (consequence) (lambda (alternative) ((pred consequence) alternative)))))
```

You might be wondering why I allow `define` since it isn't `lambda`. Well you don;t need it. It is just for convenience since with it you can try it out:

```
(((if true) 
  'result-true) 
 'result-false) 
; ==> result-true
```

Instead of using the totally equal version:

```
((lambda (pred) 
  (lambda (consequence) 
     (lambda (alternative) 
       ((pred consequence) alternative)))) 
 (lambda (true) (lambda (false) true))
  'result-true 
     'result-false)
```

Your function `church` is not lambda calculus since it does not return a church number and it takes more than one argument which is a violation. I have seen scheme functions to produce chuck numbers but any chuck number you should be able to do this to get the integer value:

```
((church-number add1) 0)
```

eg. zero:

```
(((lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)) add1) 0) ; ==> 0
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation. Why does the church number only allow lambdas with one argument? Is there a reason or it's more just a thought-experiment?

Comment: Defining only single-argument functions allows a simpler set of axioms, and it's easy to simulate n-ary functions with one-argument functions, so there's no real downside. (Except convenience, of course, which doesn't really matter since we're doing mathematics instead of writing practical programs).

Comment: @David542 That's just how lambda calculus is made. I like [Programming with nothing by Tom Stuart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUhlNx_-wYk) and while it's Ruby it is still easy to follow for a programmer with knowledge of lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Your version presupposes the existence of primitives like cond, 0, 1, =, and -. The point of all this is to show that you can implement such primitives starting from nothing but lambda.

Comment: thanks, could you show an example of what you mean? For example where mine would fail but the above would work?

Comment: This followup doesn't really make sense. There's no case yours wouldn't work. The problem is, you're breaking the rules of engagement. You can "win" a marathon by [taking the subway for most of the trip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosie_Ruiz), but your race time is invalid in that case. Likewise, you have derived a function that acts like the church function `+`, but you did it using more than just lambda. This isn't what the exercise was trying to show you.

Comment: oh I see what you mean now. Using just lambdas and not allowing other primitives that I'm using.

Comment: one question though: does it only allow one argument with the lambda or may it use zero or two or more?

Answer (score 1):

> SICP defines the Church numerals for positive numbers as follows:
>
> ```
>  (define zero (lambda (f) (lambda (x) x)))
>  (define (add-1 n)
>      (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f (n f) x))))
> ```

No, it doesn't. The correct definitions are

```
(define zero  (lambda (f)  (lambda (x)  x)))
(define (add-1 n)
              (lambda (f)  (lambda (x)  (f  ((n f) x)))))
```

`f` is  a "successor step", and `x` is "zero value".

`(f ((n f) x))` means, *do* with `f` and `x` whatever `n` would be doing with `f` and `x`, and then do `f`  one more time to the result.

In other words, *transform* the "zero value" with the "successor step" function *one more times* than `n` would be transforming it.

Now,

```
> ((zero add1) 0)
0
> (((add-1 zero) add1) 0)
1
> (((add-1 (add-1 zero)) add1) 0)
2
```

etc. Or,

```
> (define plus1 (lambda (x) (cons '() x)))

> ((zero plus1) '(NIL))
'(NIL)
> (((add-1 zero) plus1) '(NIL))
'(() NIL)
> (((add-1 (add-1 zero)) plus1) '(NIL))
'(() () NIL)
```

Hopefully you can see how the Church numbers could be defined as binary functions as well:

```
(define zero  (lambda (f x)  x))
(define (add-1 n)
              (lambda (f x)  (f  (n f x))))

(define plus1 (lambda (x) (cons '() x)))

(zero add1 0)                    ;=> 0
((add-1 zero) add1 0)            ;=> 1
((add-1 (add-1 zero)) add1 0)    ;=> 2

(zero plus1 '(NIL))                    ;=> '(NIL)
((add-1 zero) plus1 '(NIL))            ;=> '(() NIL)
((add-1 (add-1 zero)) plus1 '(NIL))    ;=> '(() () NIL)
```

producing the same results as before.